# What is the name of the wires that connect to front_panel from PC case?

Tags: motherboard, wiring

I need to find extension for mentioned wires but don't know how to google them, since I don't know their name.

Here is a picture:

[image: wires]

Comment: I've never heard any special names for them. They were just wires with connectors that had some printing on them to label what they went to from the motherboard manufacturer. Perhaps it would be best to vote to migrate this to SuperUser and see if someone there would know.

Comment: Although you might have luck if you were to google for something like "front panel wires pc case extenders"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've always called them front panel header connectors. Some call it the header block on the board.

They sell extensions [here](http://www.frozencpu.com/cat/l3/g2/c34/s276/list/p1/Cables-Wire_Management-Extension_Cables-Page1.html).

Answer (score 5):

They're called wires.  Really, they're just copper wires.

Having said that, you may have more luck if you search on system panel cables/wires or motherboard cables/wires.

Comment: "They're called wires." 